# Retrieve tags data in post body

Tags: functions, templates, tags, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to retrieve tags data and output it in post body inside a template.

```
<a class="tag-button w-button" href="<!--Tag Link-->"
style="background-color: <!--Tag Color--> ">
<!--Tag Name--> </a>
```

I use default WP Taxonomy for tags, and I created a custom field "tag-color" for Tags using ACF. Does anyone have an idea of what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Sure, that's possible. But where are you thinking of putting that code? In a template, a function, a widget? That determines how you can retrieve the data.

Comment: @cjbj I want to put it inside post template

Comment: A post can have many tags. All have the same color or are they different by tag?

Comment: @cjbj yeah i want to output every tag with each having different color. Color is specified in "tag-color" custom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this: modify the existing `the_tags` function or build your own.

`the_tags` ultimately relies on [`get_the_term_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/), which returns a list of hyperlinked tags. You would have to use regular expressions to add classes and styles to that using a filter. That would be quite cumbersome.

So, my preferred approach would be to construct a function yourself. Start with an [array of tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags) and loop through them:

```
$all_tags = wp_get_post_tags (get_the_ID(), array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all'));
$output = "";
foreach ($all_tags as $tag) {
  $tag_style =  // get that from ACF
  $tag_link  =  get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
  $tag_name  =  $tag->name;
  $output .= '<a class="tag-button w-button" href="' . $tag_link . '" style="' . $tag_style . '">' . $tag_name . '</a>';
  }
echo $output;
```

Note: I didn't test this code, so some debuggin may be necessarry.

Comment: it gives me in an error on the line with $tag_link: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array in..."

Comment: Like I said debugging  .. the function apparently returns an object, not an array, so its `$tag->term_id` to get to the item.

Comment: Thanks now its working! However except $tag_style (          $tag_style = get_field("tag_color", $tag->term_id);)

Comment: Glad it works. I'll update the answer for the object stuff. Please accept the answer to let the system know this question can be closed.

Comment: Not exactly, I still cant retrieve ACF field "tag_color" :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you have trouble retrieving information from ACF your best bet is to ask at their own forum: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: That worked for me ($tag_style = get_field( 'tag_color', "post_tag_$tag->term_id" );) Thank you for the help